# Operator > not defined for T

Tags: go

trying to check if a given number is less than the other or not, so wrote the below:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type T interface {}

func Less(i, j T) bool {
    return i > j
}
```

But got the below error:

```sh
# command-line-arguments
.\hashmap.go:23:11: invalid operation: i > j (operator > not defined on interface)
```

How can I add such mathematical operations to general type element (number or string)?

Comment: what should happen if i try to do `T(http.DefaultClient) > T(15)` ? (it is not possible to do that)

Comment: You should do insertion type in the less function...if you sure that j is comparable

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible in Go. Ordering operations are only defined only for numeric types, and interface{} is not a numeric type.

Comment: @BurakSerdar : it might be possible with type insertion in the less function no ?

Comment: Do you mean type assertion? Yes, but if you know the type, why pass interface{}?

Comment: What is supposed to be the type of i in Less func ?

Comment: @BurakSerdar : yes i mean type assetion....sorry for this typo....what do you think of this : https://play.golang.org/p/1U-Ze0-WV5m this could be published as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interface` is not a type, nor is it a generic value representing intersection of all types like `string` and `int`. When you ask for whether `a` is greater than or equal to `b`, you'll have to also specify which exact types those two belong (implicitly, they should have the same type), to answer that question. Similarly, Go also needs that information. Doing that for `interface` can be come a little cumbersome. However, there are a couple of ways:

1. Define the `Less` function individually on both types:

```
func LessString(n1, n2 string) bool {
    return strings.Compare(n1, n2) == -1
}

// no need to define a less function, but whatever
func LessInt(n1, n2 int) bool {
    return n1 < n2
}
```

Or, using type aliases:

```
type Name string
type Age int

func (name Name) Less(compare string) bool {
    return strings.Compare(string(name), compare) == -1
}

func (age Age) LessInt(compare int) bool {
    return int(age) < compare
}
```

2. A second way to implement `Less` functionality on `interface` would be to do type assertions:

```
// This isn't all that useful, but whatever
type T interface{}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Less(10, 20))
    fmt.Println(Less("10", "20"))
}

func Less(t1, t2 T) bool {
    switch v1 := t1.(type) {
    case string:
        return strings.Compare(v1, t2.(string)) < 0   // import "strings"
        // return v1 < t2.(string)
    case int:
        return v1 < t2.(int)
    }

    return false
}
```

There is no way in Go to define operators over types. It prefers adding functions to achieve that. Many standard library modules follow similar patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, considering I need to do them for specific function, the second option `type assertions` worked perfectly for me